# Getting the value of a get request in Struts 2

Tags: html, forms, jsp, struts2, glassfish

I feel like I may be really close to the solution but I just can't grasp it.
The basic flow of the program: first you fill out a form and submit it. The action class will store the object in a session. The second page uses iterator to display all the names and hyperlink them so that when you click on a name it takes you to a page where you can edit the info (so the third page is a form pre-populated with all the info from the object the user clicks on). The data is sent using get but I can't extract that value passed to set it as the textfield's value.

Here is some code to clarify:
first page (adding initial information)

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Add a Contact </h1>
    <s:form action="ContactAction" namespace="/example" method="post" >

        <s:textfield name="firstName" label="First Name" size="20" />

        <s:textfield name="lastName" label="Last Name" size="20" />

        <s:submit value="Submit"/>
    </s:form>
</body>
```

The second page (contact information is displayed and hyperlinked)

```
 <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
 <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <s:url action="index.action" var="urlTag" />


    <s:a href="%{urlTag}">Add Another Contact</s:a>


     <table border="1">

                <s:iterator value="#session.contacts" var="contact">
                    <tr>
                        <s:url value="http://localhost:8080/Project/example/EditContact.jsp" var="urlTag" includeParams="get" >
                            <s:param name="firstName"> <s:property value="firstName"/> </s:param>
                            <s:textfield label="First Name" name="firstName" key="firstName" required="true" size="25" />
                        </s:url>
                        <td>
                            <s:property  value="lastName"/>
                            <s:a href="%{urlTag}"> <s:property value="lastName"/> </s:a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </s:iterator>
            </table>
```

as you can see, above (the second page), firstName is displayed successfully in a textfield. 
When you click on last name, it send the information through a get request (It successfully does so because I can see the ?firstName=bob in the url)

Third page (where the form should be pre-populated with the data)

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Edit a Contact </h1>
    <s:form action="ContactAction" namespace="/example" method="post" >

      <s:param name="firstName"> <s:property value="firstName"/> </s:param>
                 <s:textfield label="First Name" name="firstName" key="firstName"  value="%{contact.firstName}" required="true" size="25" />
         <s:property value="lastName" />
        <s:textfield name="lastName" label="Last Name" size="20" />



        <s:submit value="Submit"/>
    </s:form>
</body>
```

The code for page 3 doesn't populate the `firstName` textfield with the `firstName` value (even though it is successfully passed with the get)

Does struts have an equivalent of PHP's `$_GET['firstName']`?
How can I get the textfield to populate with the get value passed?

I'm pulling my hair trying to figure this out! Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Where is the actions class?

Comment: I thought it unnecessary for the question. It's long(I can't see why that would be an issue)

Comment: Really unclear :| And your (only relevant parts of!) Action code is needed to guess what is happening. JSPs alone explains almost nothing...

Comment: If you don't provide the required parts to solve the issue we can't do much...

Answer (score 0):

Of course it has equivalent, but to populate the form you don't need that, because the form should be populated automatically. For this purpose you need to create the action bean properties with the name of textfields and initialize them. As long as you keep data in the session you could retrieve the session values to the action properties. See how it's done in the simple [Hello World](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/hello-world.html) application.